# ¿como dar valor a un parámetro atreves de un metodo? php poo

Tags: php, poo, class

mi problema es el siguiente, debo generar una clase que contenga 3 parametros private, dentro 2 metodos, "calcular_Edad" (el cual debe ser private) y la otra imprimir caracteristicas en public, ya que es la que debo mostrar, la cual tambien debe contener la edad. lei la documentacion, etc y no consegui encontrar solucion al problema. les dejo el codigo:

```
<?php 
class Usuarios{
private $nombre;
private $apellido;
private $fecha_nacimiento;



function __construct($nom,$ape,$edad){
    $this->nombre = $nom;
    $this->apellido = $ape;
    $this->fecha_nacimiento=$edad;

}
// funcion para calcular edad
private function calcular_edad(){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
    $fecha_Actual = date("Y/m/d");
    $fechacalc = strtotime($fecha_Actual);
    $años = strtotime($this->fecha_nacimiento);
    if($años>= $fechacalc){
        echo "<p>error en la fecha</p>";
    }else{
        $calcular =  $fechacalc - $años;
        $dias = intval($calcular/86400);
        // calcula los años
       $edad_Actual = ($dias / 364);   
    //el probelma esta aca
    }
}
// metodo para imprimir el resultado 
public function imprime_caracteristicas() {
    echo "<p> Nombre: ".$this->nombre." ".$this->apellido."</p>";
    echo "<p> Edad:".$edad_Actual."</p>";
}
}?>
```

El cual despues muestro en un script incluyendolo en el index (con include), le dejo el script:

```
<?php       
include("usuarios.php");

    $user = new Usuarios('pepe','martines','1990/05/03');
    $user->imprime_caracteristicas();
?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo, acabe aclarar que estoy aprendiendo asi que puede haber error muy comunes, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin entrar a detalles podemos dividir las funciones en 2:

- Las que retornan algo
- Y las que no

Las que no retornan algo, en otro leguajes se llaman subrutinas y en otros se dice que retornan `void` (vacío). Tu función `imprime_caracteristicas` es de este tipo

Las que retorna algo usan la palabra reservada `return` para ello, por ejemplo una función que retorne la suma de 2 numeros

```
function suma($a,$b){
   return $a + $b;
}
$resultado = suma(2,3); //5
```

Tu función `calcular_edad` debería ser de ese tipo.

```
private function calcular_edad(){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
    $fecha_Actual = date("Y/m/d");
    $fechacalc = strtotime($fecha_Actual);
    $años = strtotime($this->fecha_nacimiento);

    if($años>= $fechacalc){
        return "<p>error en la fecha</p>";
    }

    $calcular =  $fechacalc - $años;
    $dias = intval($calcular/86400);
    // calcula los años
    return ($dias / 364);
    
}
public function imprime_caracteristicas() {
    echo "<p> Nombre: ".$this->nombre." ".$this->apellido."</p>";
    echo "<p> Edad:".$this->calcular_edad()."</p>";
}
```

Ahora fíjate que los cambios a tu código son pequeños

- En vez de utilizar una variable `$edad_Actual` retornamos el valor directamente
- Si hay un error, retornamos el mensaje
- El último `else` no es necesario, porque si entra al `if` retornará un valor y la función no sigue ejecutándose más allá de ese punto

---

La manera anterior es como yo lo haría, ahora para responder específicamente a tu pregunta, sobre como asignar el valor en una función, se hace igual que en el constructor, es decir usando `$this->`

```
<?php 
class Usuarios{
private $nombre;
private $apellido;
private $fecha_nacimiento;

private $edad; //agregamos una nueva variable

function __construct($nom,$ape,$fecha){
    $this->nombre = $nom;
    $this->apellido = $ape;
    $this->fecha_nacimiento=$fecha;
    $this->calcular_edad(); //llamamos a la función para que haga el cálculo y asigne un valor a la nueva variable

}
// funcion para calcular edad
private function calcular_edad(){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
    $fecha_Actual = date("Y/m/d");
    $fechacalc = strtotime($fecha_Actual);
    $años = strtotime($this->fecha_nacimiento);
    if($años>= $fechacalc){
        echo "<p>error en la fecha</p>";
    }else{
        $calcular =  $fechacalc - $años;
        $dias = intval($calcular/86400);
        // calcula los años
       $this->edad = ($dias / 364);  //Asignamos el valor a la variable
    
    }
}
// metodo para imprimir el resultado 
public function imprime_caracteristicas() {
    echo "<p> Nombre: ".$this->nombre." ".$this->apellido."</p>";
    echo "<p> Edad:".$this->edad."</p>";
}
}?>
```